# Closing a window that was replaced

Tags: javascript

I need a way to make an "Exit" button.  I have a redirect page that opens a new window with JavaScript using `_self`, so it replaces the window.  The next thing I need to do, is use JavaScript to close that window.

Now, I guess the problem is, that since the page was replaced, it does not remember it was opened by JavaScript, so it can't be closed.  Can this be done using any other language?

Comment: Does using `window.close()` not work?

Comment: Nope, my guess is that it does not "remember" that it was opened by JS, since the original window is closed (replaced)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, someone told me that javascript could only close a window if that window remembered that it was opened by the javascript...or something like that.

Well, I might have discovered an exploit just now:

```
    <div style="width: 128px; height: 32px; background-color:green;" onclick="doStuff()">Click me</div>


    <script>

        function doStuff()
        {
            var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
            myWindow.document.write("This page will close in 3 seconds, for real...\<script\> setTimeout(function() { window.close(); }, 3000);\<\/script\>");
        }        

    </script>
```

Did you see what I just did there, I sent a block of code to the newly opened page , and the new page ran it (at least on my chrome). So between the script tags, you could generate a button or something which closes the document (instead of the timeout function).

Comment: And i guess I'll need to paste it inside my redirect page?
Also, I'm trying.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. Could you please say exactly how you set up everything? Also, i guess you are opening it directly. I'm using my uploaded server hosting, so it might work only when on your computer.

Comment: As a super dirty workaround, you could write your whole redirect page (as a string, + the script at the end) in the myWindow.docuument.write(). I just wrote a simple html page with the markup and script, just to illustrate. 
I know it doesn't work if you do it like this: 
var myWindow = window.open("example.html", "_self");

Anyways, if you provided a bit more markup and code, I could see the problem more clearly.

Comment: default.php: '<body onLoad="javascript:window.open("STUFF","_self")">'